# Javascript Integration Testing Framework

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, integration-testing, signalr

In our current project we have used ASP.NET with Telerik library, and up until recent we have used MVP (model view presenter) pattern. In this scenario view was designed to be dumb that it did not hold any business logic and polling mechanism based on a timer used to get data from the presenter down and show it in the view. With this structure testing the application with integration tests (tests all the way down to the database) was easy.

Recently we have moved to SignalR and we have added significant JavaScript logic into the views in order to process the events fired from the SignalR, but with this our integration tests are having less code coverage and integrity of tests are not that good (test is passing even-though application itself is failing).

So, does anyone used a framework which can be used to simulate the JavaScript execution (including signalR library) along with the C# code so that the complete scenario can be tested?

Comment: Have you looked at Chutzpah yet? http://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah We used a combination of Chutzpah, which uses phantom as a headless browser to integrate our js tests and signalr hub api. If you are interested, I can post more details.

Comment: this one seems interesting... Please provide more details if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used [Chutzpah](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah) to run our Javascript Logic and also test our Signalr Server HUB API.

Our Javascript tests were created using QUnit (chutzpah also supports Jasmine).

Chutzpah's [test runner](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0) allows you to run  your js tests inside Visual Studio by leveraging phantom.js, which uses a headless browser. You can run your server and js logic and verify/run the results in Visual Studio. Also, we self hosted our HUB using OWIN from signalr, which worked great for simulating our tests.

Chutzpah provides other capabilities, so I suggest checking it out to see what works best for you.

I would also check out how [Jabbr](https://github.com/JabbR/JabbR) runs tests. They also use Chutzpah along with some more sophisticated techniques that may work well for you.

Comment: Chutzpah doesn't have any means for integration testing (from the original question), only unit testing.